# convergence of series : rational with exponentials

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this infinite series below, not sure how to handle the alternating term in the bottom. I am guessing i could use triangle inequality on the bottom, then the absolute of the alternating term would become positive.
Not sure if i can replace or remove this term. Need some help

$$
\sum \frac{7^n}{(-2)^n +5^n}
$$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint:  think about the behavior of your terms for large $n$.

Comment: I might've had a little brain fart on my answer lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to notice that
$$
5^n + (-2)^n = 5^n + (-1)^n\cdot 2^n \leq 5^n + 2^n \leq 5^n + 5^n = 2\cdot 5^n
$$
for every $n\geq 1$, and therefore
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{7^n}{5^n + (-2)^n} \geq \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{7^n}{2\cdot 5^n} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)^n\,.$$
Now, for $N\to\infty$, the RHS diverges to $\infty$, so...

Comment: Hi Clement, I like the way you did the inequality work on this and taking out the (-1)^n.

Comment: Thanks. Glad that helped!

Comment: Hi Clement, since we constructed here a minimum  bound of the original function, does that imply that if the minimum bound diverges then the actual series diverges.

Comment: OK, i see that is the case, i looked up the comparison test in detail, and see that is the case.

Comment: Yes (this is a simple case of the squeeze theorem, if you will). If $a_n \geq b_n$ and $b_n\to\infty$, then $a_n \to \infty$.

Comment: For some reason, i just can't see it being a special  case of the squeeze theorem though.

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to observe that

$$a_n=\frac{7^n}{(-2)^n +5^n}\ge \frac{7^n}{2^n +5^n}=\frac{(2+5)^n}{2^n +5^n}\ge1$$

and therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\ge N \to \infty$$

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why some people or a moderator put this on hold. I asked a question and people were able to answer this OK. And I chose the answer i thought was the best. SO I am surprised that people would put on HOLD a question that is already answered. I really don't see any issues at all. This question seems fairly clear. SO very odd that my questions are put on HOLD when they are already answered. I can understand if there is no answer being awarded and then it being put on hold.

Comment: @Palu I agree and voted for reopening. Bye

Comment: Thanks for your support gimusi. Really appreciate your input here.